# MySQL string cast to unsigned

Tags: mysql, string, casting, integer

If I have a string that starts with a number, then contains non-numeric characters, casting this string to an integer in MySQL will cast the first part of the string, and give no indication that it ran into any problems! This is rather annoying.

For example:

```
SELECT CAST('123' AS UNSIGNED) AS WORKS,
       CAST('123J45' AS UNSIGNED) AS SHOULDNT_WORK,
       CAST('J123' AS UNSIGNED) AS DOESNT_WORK
```

returns:

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|    WORKS    | SHOULDNT_WORK | DOESNT_WORK |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|     123     |      123      |      0      |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

This doesn't make any sense to me, as clearly, `123J45` is not a number, and certainly does not equal `123`. Here's my use case:

I have a field that contains (some malformed) zip codes. There may be mistypes, missing data, etc., and that's okay from my perspective. Because of another table storing Zip Codes as integers, when I join the tables, I need to cast the string Zip Codes to integers (I would have to pad with `0`s if I was going the other way). However, if for some reason there's an entry that contains `6023JZ1`, in *no way* would I want that to be interpreted as Zip Code `06023`. I am much happier with `6023JZ1` getting mapped to `NULL`. Unfortunately, `IF(CAST(zipcode AS UNSIGNED) <= 0, NULL, CAST(zipcode AS UNSIGNED))` doesn't work because of the problem discussed above.

How do I control for this?

Comment: Instead of casting strings to integers, cast integers to strings. [Zip codes are not integers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24192830/).

Comment: @DourHighArch, agree totally. Shoot whoever stored the ZIP codes as integers in the first place.  When was the last time you ever needed to find the sum of ZIP codes or calculated compound interest on a ZIP code?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
select (case when val rlike '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then cast(val as unsigned)
        end)
```

Many people consider it a nice feature that MySQL does not automatically produce an error when doing this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

One options is to test for just digit characters 0 thru 9 for the entire length of the string:

```
zipstr REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Based on the result of that boolean, you could return the integer value, or a NULL.

```
SELECT IF(zipstr REGEXP '^[0-9]+$',zipstr+0,NULL) AS zipnum ...
```

(note: the addition of zero is an implicit conversion to numeric)

---

Another option is to do the conversion like you are doing, and cast the numeric value back to character, and compare to the original string, to return a boolean:

```
CAST( zipstr+0 AS CHAR) = zipstr
```

(note: this second approach does allow for a decimal point, e.g.

```
CAST( '123.4'+0 AS CHAR ) = '123.4'  => 1
```

which may not be desirable if you are looking for just a valid integer